# Jquery error de sintaxis

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hola buenas estoy intentado crear unos botones que hagan `show` y `hide` según la categoría pero tengo algún error y no funciona.

Este es el `for` que monta los botones:

```
 for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                var categoria = data[i].NombreCategoria;
                if (categoria != null) {
                    categoria = categoria.split(" ").join("");
                }
                else {
                    categoria = "null";
                    data[i].NombreCategoria = "Sin categoría";
                }
                $("#ContenedorConvenios").append(""
                    + "<button class='btn btn-eco' onclick='prueba(" + categoria.toString() + ");' id='" + categoria + "'>" + data[i].NombreCategoria + "</button>"
                    + "");
                console.log("Hola" +categoria);

            }
```

Este es el código para los toggle:

```
function prueba(cat) {
    console.log("adios" + cat);
    $('#'+cat).on('click', function () {
        $('.' +cat).toggle()
    });
}
```

y esto es lo que me devuelve el console log:

```
 adios[object HTMLButtonElement] jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2 Uncaught Error:
 Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #[object HTMLButtonElement]
     at Function.fb.error (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
     at fb.tokenize (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
     at fb.select (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
     at Function.fb [as find] (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
     at m.fn.init.find (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
     at m.fn.init (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
     at m (jquery-1.11.1.min.js:2)
     at prueba (custom.js:195)
     at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (acuerdos-comerciales.html:1)
```

`adios[object HTMLButtonElement]` quiere decir que recoge todo el button.

¿Cómo hago para que solo recoja la categoría?

gracias!

Solucionado muchas gracias! 
Ahora tengo el problema de que quiero hacer toggle pero con un solo click y desconozco como hacerlo, alguien puede orientarme?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Es posible que sea por las comillas de "adios", prueba con comillas simples:

```
function prueba(cat) {
    console.log('adios' + cat);
    $('#'+cat).on('click', function () {
        $('.' +cat).toggle()
    });
}
```

La categoria que recoges tiene alguna comilla y está fallando la sintaxis?

Comment: Hola Flowen. Las frases como *"es posible"* sugieren que no estás seguro. Por favor, comprueba que tu solucion es valida antes de responder a la pregunta. Si no estas seguro, preguntale en los comentarios al autor que pruebe con ello. Mira [answer] para más informacion. Un saludo

Comment: Eso no tiene nada que ver

Comment: exacto eso no tiene nada que ver.
el caso que si la funcion prueba la pego en el html fuera de las funciones, me devuelve el codigo completo del boton

Answer (score 0):

En realidad el error es porque te faltan las comillas en el argumento de prueba:

```js
var data = [{NombreCategoria: 'categoria1'}, {NombreCategoria: 'categoria2'}, {NombreCategoria: 'categoria3'}];

for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  var categoria = data[i].NombreCategoria;
  if (categoria != null) {
      categoria = categoria.split(" ").join("");
  }
  else {
      categoria = "null";
      data[i].NombreCategoria = "Sin categoría";
  }
  $("#ContenedorConvenios").append(""
      + "<button class='btn btn-eco' onclick='prueba(\"" + categoria.toString() + "\");' id='" + categoria + "'>" + data[i].NombreCategoria + "</button>"
      + "");
  console.log("Hola" +categoria);
}

function prueba(cat) {
    console.log("adios" + cat);
    $('#'+cat).on('click', function () {
        $('.' +cat).toggle()
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ContenedorConvenios"></div>
```

Comment: muchas gracias! ya me funciona